# Compile sass and export to css using webpack 2

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I've just started a react project with webpack and I'm trying to compile my sass files and export to css using webpack but nothing seems to happen. I'm not getting any errors but i don't see any .css files the project. Any advice would be great.

My webpack config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename:'./dist/bundle.js' },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
        },{
            rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: "style-loader"},
                    {loader: "css-loader"},
                    {loader: "sass-loader"}
                ]
            }]
        }]
     },
     plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('../src/css/main.css')]
};
```

Here is the versions / dev dependencies i'm using:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I see that you're using the ExtractTextPlugin for css, but not scss. Are you also importing your scss files into your .js files?

Comment: Have you imported any `.scss` files into your entry file or any of its imported files?

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn't importing the file. When I import as SCSS and cix the Extract for SCSS it works - which is good news but my problem now is that I wanted to write SASS, when I change the ExtractText for sass and the import i get the error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja you were correct, I had a typo so the sass wasn't compiling. Fixed now, Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin documentation (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin):

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
}
```

So two things seem to be missing. First is that you didn't add the plugin in the rules, and second is that you haven't mentioned if you're importing any `.scss` files in your entry file or any of its imports.

Once you do those two things, you should be on track.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Webpack config file:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "app.css"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src.app.js'
    ],
    output: { path: __dirname, filename:'./dist/bundle.js' },
    plugins: [
        extractSass
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
      },{
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: extractSass.extract({
                loader: [{
                    loader: "css-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }]
            })
        }]
    }
}
```

The css file would be named `app.css` - feel free to use any other name.

And then in your `src/app.js` file you need to import the scss file. Without this part Webpack won't include it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import 'app.scss'; // or other file which is your main scss file


render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('appContainer'));
```

Comment: When I was configuring Webpack in my application I was struggling with paths a lot. Remember that all paths you use in scss files are relative to main scss file.

Comment: Thank alot! I can get it working by using the SCSS file extension however i've been using SASS, when I try to run webpack I get "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." - I thought the sass loader would cover this?